# UNIX : Unable to get value of env variable

Tags: unix, environment-variables

I am doing remsh to a server and reading content of a file in a for loop. File containts the path of a directory and it's name contains an env variable.

Content of file is as below. ENV_VARIABLE contains some path to a directory.

```
    $ENV_VARIABLE/somepath
```

I am running command as below.

```
    remsh server -l user ' . ./.profile;echo $ENV_VARIABLE for i in `cat filename do; echo $i;done'
```

When above command is executed, it produces below output.

```
    VALUE_OF_ENV_VARIABLE/somepath
    $ENV_VARIABLE/somepath
```

Why is ENV_VARIABLE read from file in not being replaced with it's value while same ENV_VARIABLE is replaced with it's value with 'echo' ?

How can i get value of ENV_VARIABLE when it is read from file ?

Comment: is ENV_VARIABLE in the remote ./.profile? or on the one of the calling server (ie, local) ?  if remote:  `remsh server -l user '. ./.profile ; echo "ENV_VARIABLE=$ENV_VARIABLE" ; for i in $(cat filename) ; do echo "$i" ; done'` . If locally: `remsh server -l user ". ./.profile ; echo 'ENV_VARIABLE=$ENV_VARIABLE' ; for i in $(cat filename) ; do echo \"\$i\" ; done"`  (I assume "filename" and ".profile" to both be remote)

Comment: yes, it is defined on the remote server and i am able to print it's value with echo $ENV_VARIABLE by running remsh server -l user ' . ./.profile;echo $ENV_VARIABLE'. But when I try to print it's value by reading it from file,it gives me ENV_VARIABLE instead of it's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, it's become apparent the problem is `cat filename`, which just produces the raw contents of the file without interpolation.  You need to use `eval` on that output if you want to do variable substitution.

So, what I *think* what you want is:

```
remsh server -l user ' . ./.profile;echo $ENV_VARIABLE; for i in `cat filename` ; do eval echo $i ; done'
```

*note the `eval` before using the variable obtained from the file*

Comment: It is defined in remote shell and I can print it's value by echo $ENV_VARIABLE. File also contains same variable but when I try to print it's value by echo it gives me ENV_VARIABLE not it's value.

Comment: because you're just using `cat` to output the file, this does not interpolate variables.